# Update View with updated data in Android

Tags: android

I am noob in Android. Suppose I have two `Activity` in my android app.

`Activity` A and B, currently I am on Activity A then on click on one button I am now Activity `B`. Here From Activity B I want to update some view with updated data that is in Activity A. I got updated data in Activity B so Should I use here `LocalBroadCastReceiver` for this or anything ?? so that When I press back then app should show me updated data in Activity A

Should we use our custom callback here to update the UI view data of Activity A from Activity B ??

Comment: which type of view are you using ? what type of data you want to show , and what type of data is getting updated

Comment: Like any `TextView` and any text data that I get in Activity B

Comment: are u storing that data some where ?

Answer (score 2):

No, you shouldn't use `BroadcastReceiver` for that. The method depends on the size of data you want to transfer from `Activity B` to `Activity A`. If it's quite small, you can start `Activity B` with [startActivityForResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle%29) and then get data back at the [onActivityResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) method (in `Activity B` you should use [setResult](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) once you are done). If the size of data is quite big, it's better to use `DB` for storing it instead of keeping it in memory.

Comment: What about If I there are four activities A->B->C->D then I am getting updated data in D then want to set that data in TextView of A. then should I use `onActivityResult` ?

Comment: @Mick in such a case you should use `DB`, definitely. You can can make a cascade of `startActivityForResult`, but I think it's weird.

Comment: Suppose I get only one word from web api in D then for this I should use DB , How this can be good approach I don't think so to use here DB

Comment: @Mick well, for such small piece of data you can use `SharedPreferences`

Comment: Why here it is not good practice to use LocalBroadCastReceiver ?

Comment: @Mick because they are useless for sending data between activities. From docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html If registering a receiver in your Activity.onResume() implementation, you should unregister it in Activity.onPause(). (You won't receive intents when paused, and this will cut down on unnecessary system overhead)

Comment: so where are LocalBroadCast Receiver use for communicating for what ?

Answer (score 1):

okay , there are multiple ways to do it :-

1. you can use a static variable to store you data that too of application level ( might not be a good approach ) check the value of vairable in onResume() and set it to the view.
2. you can use sharedpreferences if your data is not that large , store the data in Activity B and fetch it on onResume() method of activity A.
3. as @nikis has told you
4. if your data is too large store it in db.

I dont think broadcastreceiver fits right in your scenario !!